# Need to create a computer account in active directory using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

So I have queried Active Directory before and I know about disabling accounts and creating user accounts. However, I need to be able to kind of create and reserve computer names. I am writing a .net ASP program for it. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You want the DirectoryServices namespace. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PaulSwetz I am using it. Thats not the problem. The directory services doesnt have a method for creating a object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example of how to add computer

```
 DirectoryEntry de01 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Computers,DC=fabrikam,DC=com");
 DirectoryEntry newComputer = de01.Children.Add("CN=New Computer", "computer");
 newComputer.CommitChanges();
```